# Magento 2 Translations not working

Tags: magento2, localisation

I'm trying to translate some text in the checkout page:

> "Provided Zip/Postal Code seems to be invalid."

However, when I add the following to `frontend/..theme../Magento_Checkout/i18n/en_US.csv` and re-deploy, the translation isn't there:

> "Provided Zip/Postal Code seems to be invalid.","Test."

I cleared cache as well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check my updated answer. I hope now working for you.

Comment: Related: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/299697/1883

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Create a directory `app/i18n/Vendorname/en_US`

Issue command:

`bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases --output "app/i18n/Vendorname/en_US/en_US.csv" --magento` This will collect all the translatable phrases in csv file and place it in the specified path. Make changes to the csv file as per your requirement and when ready issue command:

```
bin/magento i18n:pack app/i18n/Vendorname/en_US/en_US.csv -d en_US
```

This will deploy the translations from your file.

clear the cache etc and you should see your changes.

Comment: This looks promising. It says the language package was saved successfully but the translation is still not there..

Comment: When I do the collect-phrases command again, the translation is back to what it was. Why isn't it saving?

Comment: That's normal behavior, when you recollect phrases it overrides your changes because Magento has recollected all default phrases. Process is you collect phrases, make your changes and deploy them, once deployed you can go in the concerned module let's say you made change for Add to Cart to Add to Bag, you can go to vendor/module-catalog/i18n/en_US.csv and look for your change. Just retested this and it works as it should. Make sure you're changing the second instance in translation and clearing the cache properly. You can also try deploying static content once again.

Comment: Great thanks, it works indeed. However, some translations don't come through. The 'Example:' translation and 'Required fields' aren't translated. How come?

Comment: Found the problem. I had to php bin/magento setup:upgrade. After that my site was messed up, but then deplying the theme fixed it. No idea why this worked. Thanks

Comment: No worries, glad it helped and yes translation for elements that use UI components, validations etc require redeployment of static files (static-content-deploy) to work.

Comment: When i run `bin/magento i18n:pack app/i18n/Vendorname/en_US/en_US.csv -d en_US` it give me error  **[RuntimeException]     
  Not enough arguments.** can you help me

Comment: You're changing Vendorname with your Vendor (directory). Ensure that en_US.csv exists in the specified location before running the command.

Comment: And how do I translate in german? Replacing en_US everywhere with de_DE ?

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem on my Magento 2 website, tried all sorts of suggestions how to fix it but the only thing that worked for me was -

1. go to `/pub/static/frontend/<theme>/<theme>/<language for example pl_PL>`
2. Find `js-translation.json` and delete it (make a copy of it just in case!)
3. Go back to your magento root folder and run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy pl_PL`
4. Then run `php bin/magento cache:flush`

That's it. If you go back to `/pub/static/frontend/<theme>/<theme>/<language for example pl_PL>` folder, notice that `js-translation.json` have been generated again.

This problem happens because when you run static deploy, magento generates js-translation.json file with all your translations inserted into this one file and calls it in every time the page is loaded. So when it's already generated and usually empty, it cannot overwrite it with new information. By deleting it and regenerating it will solve the problem.

Hope this is going to help somebody.

Comment: Hi @Pinky_P, in my case the js-translation.json is updated with my expected translation. But it not showing in frontend. Could you please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: js-translation.json is not updating with the correct data from csv file

Answer (score 4):

You can change only text which is written in translation

Like : `$this->__("Sample Taxt");`

Suggested text not written in translation so you can not change it with translation.

If you want to change it, you can find it in **JS** file which is located  :

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-rates-validator.js
```

**Note :** You have to override **JS** file to in your theme.

Delete pub/static/*

Run Command :

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy 

php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Delete browser cache.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for some reason.

Comment: I copied that file, changed the translation, and put it in
app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Checkout/web/js/model, re-deployed and cleaned cache. But no change..

Comment: check my updated answer. I hope now working for you.

Comment: This indeed worked. However, the solution provided by Devtype suits my needs more in this case. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Tried editing the following, but nothing worked:

```
app/i18n/vendor/module/en_US.csv
app/design/frontend/package/theme/i18n/en_US.csv
app/design/frontend/package/theme/web/js-translation.json
app/design/frontend/package/theme/web/js-translation-en_US.json
```

Later on, found this answer and it worked: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/299697/1883

It says:

> Core Module translations will not be overridden in custom theme so you
> need to place the new translations in your custom module folder.
> Create an empty module or use your existing module.

- I created a new module (`app/code/MyCompany/MyModule`)
- Created a new file `i18n/en_US.csv` inside the module (`app/code/MyCompany/MyModule/i18n/en_US.csv`)
- Added necessary translation text in the csv file.
- Enabled the module and the translation finally got reflected in the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Just a reminder...

Magento stores some translation data in the browser storage.

You may have to clean browser storage items in addition to Magento internal caches.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Always you need to use
like: `<?php echo __('Word To Translate'); ?>`
to translate any words in magento.

After that you need to add translated words in your locale csv file which is located in **app/locale/{lang_ISO}/Your_Module.csv**

like **app//locale/fr_FR/Mage_Catalog.csv.**

Magento will automatically coinsider this translationat the frontend.

Comment: The question is tagged as Magento 2 but this is a Magento 1 solution