# Magento 2 JS Translation Not Working

Tags: magento2.2.2, js-translation

Is this a magento bug or is something I am doing it working

I had created my translation file in my module **i18n**. For testing purpose I just modified few text.

> app/code/Vendor/Namespace/i18n/en_US.csv

```
"Do you want to remove the item from cart?","Just Remove?"
"Login","Sign In"
```

In My JS File I have this piece of code which I need to translate

```
        deleteItem: function (data) {
            var self = this;
            confirm({
                content: $t('Do you want to remove the item from cart?'),
                actions: {
                    confirm: function () {
                        alert('Done');
                    },
                    always: function (event) {
                        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    }
                }
            });

        },
```

But the translation for the code does not work. When I deploy static content it does not adds the translation in `js-translation.json` file.

Does any one have a workaround?

Comment: This solution should help you with this problem https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/260843/42841

Answer (score 1):

It may be due to Magento bug. In `vendor/magento/module-translation/Model/Json/PreProcessor.php`

```
$area = $this->areaList->getArea($areaCode);
$area->load(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::PART_TRANSLATE);
```

needs to be:

```
$area = $this->areaList->getArea($areaCode);
$area->load(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::PART_DESIGN);
$area->load(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::PART_TRANSLATE);
```

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8508#issuecomment-279332346

Answer (score 0):

Please clear cache and check while cleaning cache it will flush translate cache as well. 
In Magento 2 there is mage/translate js library and that you can require in your js and use it like

> $.mage.__("your text here");

You will get translated text.

Comment: yes `mage/translate` has already been defined and I have tried clearing cache and re deploy static content. But my JS translation does not appears in `pub/static/js-translation.json` file.