# Magento 2: Cannot override translation csv for admin area

Tags: magento2.3

I am override and added local en_US.csv file with below path

> app/code/Magento/Customer/i18n with en_US.csv

Changed text "**Force Sign-In**" to "**Force Login**" and **clear cache**. The translation is not working.

*Any help is highly appreciated.*

Comment: You cannot create Magento/Customer extension inside code folder. Please create custom extension with your company and module name - https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/      And place the i18n folder inside your module

Comment: I need to translate "Force Sign-In" button in magento admin customer section.

Comment: @BhavinPethani you have checked admin language en_US or en_GB

Comment: @RakeshDonga Let me try and update you.

Comment: @BhavinPethani you have checked?

Comment: @RakeshDonga can you share with me path for admin language en_US or en_GB file path.

Comment: @BhavinPethani like this below path..
app/i18n/Mageplaza/en_gb/
Ref: https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-english-united-kingdom-language-pack

Answer (score 1):

> Core Module translations will not be overridden in custom theme so you need to place the new translations in your custom module folder. Create an empty module or use your existing module.

Just Copy this file `vendor\magento\module-customer\i18n\en_US.csv` and paste it to any of your extension `app\code\vendor\module\i18n`

**Alternate solutions**

Create a sample module and  override `InvalidateTokenButton` class,as below code

1. Create file `app/code/Stackexchange/MyTestModule/etc/di.xml`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="\Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\InvalidateTokenButton"
               type="\Stackexchange\MyTestModule\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\InvalidateTokenButton"/>
   </config>
   ```
2. Create  `InvalidateTokenButton.php`  in `app/code/Stackexchange/MyTestModule/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/InvalidateTokenButton.php`

   ```
   <?php

   namespace Stackexchange\MyTestModule\Block\Adminhtml\Edit;


   class InvalidateTokenButton extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\InvalidateTokenButton
   {
   /**
    * Get button data.
    *
    * @return array
    */
   public function getButtonData()
   {
       $customerId = $this->getCustomerId();
       $data = [];
       if ($customerId) {
           $deleteConfirmMsg = __("Are you sure you want to revoke the customer's tokens?");
           $data = [
               'label' => __('Force Sign'),
               'class' => 'invalidate-token',
               'on_click' => 'deleteConfirm("' . $deleteConfirmMsg . '", "' . $this->getInvalidateTokenUrl() . '")',
               'sort_order' => 65,
               'aclResource' => 'Magento_Customer::invalidate_tokens',
           ];
       }
       return $data;
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: Using custom module translation is working for website front-end, but translation is not working for magento back-end text (admin penal)

Comment: Check once with my given answer

Comment: I am already try that using custom module, but it's not working for magento admin text translation.