# Can't run my validation translated csv

Tags: magento2, translate

I'm having some issues with translating the validation csv file. I did go to public_html/lib/web/i18n - downloaded the existing en_US.csv file and translated it. I cleared all the empty lines, as it is said in the Magento 2 documentation and uploaded it to the same folder with name bg_BG.csv for my native language.

Then I did - `php bin/magento i18n:pack lib/web/i18n/bg_BG.csv -d bg_BG` as shown in here [Magento 2 Translations not working](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142285/magento-2-translations-not-working)
I also did navigate to public_html folder first with `cd` command so I can run the command.(otherwise it gives me - "magento no such a command or directory"

The result is this -

```
> ` In AbstractFile.php line 112:
> 
>   Missed context in row #1.   Each row has to consist of 4 columns
> original phrase, translation, context type, context value `
```

and nothing yet in the frontend [image]

Comment: Any idea pls ? Anybody - (angel emote icon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-bulgarian-language-pack
If you have install using composer, location of csv will be here `magento_root/vendor/mageplaza/magento-2-bulgarian-language-pack/bg_BG.csv`

Edit **bg_BG.csv**
add new row

> "English Text" "Translated text" "module" "Magento_Customer"
>
> "This is a required field" "Translated text" "lib" "web"

Deploy static file using this command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy bg_BG -f
```

Comment: Dude, your method translated 95% of the website, anyway it does not apply to the "This field is required." and another popup messages for the registration form. It is not subzero wins-fatality for the case. According to another post I found in here I have to edit the validation.js file, which is not reccomendet at all, so I will try it on a local host. Thanks a lot for your answer. You are awsm. HUG

Comment: You can search text using this command grep -Rw 'app' -e 'This is a required field.'

Comment: As text from js file magento2 lib $.mage.__('This is a required field.'). Instead of module, here we can use "lib" "web"

Comment: As long as I remember, the bg_BG.csv file, which I downloaded with the bulgarian language pack from the github link was - "English text" "Translated text", "lib, "web", but it didn't do the trick :( . Anyway, now i located all the strings in public_html/lmageib/web/ validation.js file. I had an idea creating an i18n folder with a .csv file in this location with "lib" "web". Do you think it will do the trick ?

Comment: I've checked bg_BG file. Here dot is missing in csv. In your snapshot, there is dot after sentence. You can create new row and use "This is a required field." "Translated text." "lib" "web" . We need to exactly copy all text under comma $.mage.__('This is a required field.')

Comment: Ok dude. Thanks, I will try it and chek the result. But after a drink, because here is 6:30 pm. Cheers