# Translations are not reflected in store view

Tags: magento2.4

Wishing you all a Happy New Year.
I have Magento 2 installation with Main website in default en_US locale.

I have to create an Arabic version and I created a separate website, store view having locale set to Arabic(Saudi Arabia) - ar_SA . Store ID is 3.

For the translations I am using a custom module which adds phrases and translations to Magento db table `translation` . As I have read, `translation` tables entries gets top priority of over other methods.

The en_US phrases in `translation` table for default store view (with store id 0, loads fine. Any change is immediately reflected in frontend.

However for the custom store view (store id 3) does not appear in frontend after switching store in to it in frontend. It shows original phrases.

[image: A sample translation entry in db table]
Having above translation for phrase 'Add to cart' in Arabic for store id 3, still in frontend it is shown as 'Add to cart' in English. Cache clearing, static content depolyment, clearing of var/view_preprocessed, pub/static are already done.

It is highly appreciated if someone please guide me to resolve this.

P.S : There is an `en_US` language pack installed. No language pack for `ar_SA` is in use.

Thanks and Best Regards

Indunil

Comment: Cloud you please check this link :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/142291/85907

Comment: Please edit your question to add the PHP code which adds translations to Magento DB table `translation`. If you don't know where is it located, please compress the module and upload it somewhere then paste the link here, I'll take a look.